# JSDoc @param - reference class from another module

Tags: node.js, jsdoc

I have 2 Node modules. In module A I have the following definition:

```js
/**
 * HTTP Client
 * @module src/http/client
 */
/**
 * A HTTP Client
 * @alias src/http/client
 */
class HTTPClient {
   [... class def with documented methods etc]
}
module.exports = HTTPClient
```

And now in module B I want to say that the first constructor parameter should be of type HTTPClient. So I tried the following

```js
class PackageFactory {
    /**
     * @param {module:src/http/client} httpClient - the HTTPClient instance
     */
    constructor(httpClient) {
       this._httpClient = httpClient
    }
}
```

I also tried a few variations but it never worked. Within module B the httpClient is always of type "any". What do I have to change so I can see the class member of HTTPClient in module B?

Comment: Can you try `@param {module:src/http/client~HTTPClient} httpClient`?

Comment: seems to have no effect. Or is this probably sth that visual studio code, which I am using, is not properly displaying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was easier then I thought. There is no need to include the module paths (aka longname) or anything.

```
const HTTPClient = require('../http/client')
class PackageFactory {
    /**
     * @param {HTTPClient} httpClient - the HTTPClient instance that shall be used to make requests
     */
    constructor(httpClient) {
       this._httpClient = httpClient
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you then get warnings that HTTPClient is unused.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the `HTTPClient is unused` error that any linter will give you, you can actually import the class in the `@param` field itself. This makes the doc a bit less easy to read, but you get autocompletion at design time, a nice tradeoff.

Note that you can combine this with the `compilerOptions.paths` option of `tsconfig.json` to create aliases that will make those documentation-imports look better.

```
class PackageFactory {
    /**
     * @param {import('../http/client')} httpClient - the HTTPClient instance that shall be used to make requests
     */
    constructor(httpClient) {
       this._httpClient = httpClient
    }
}
```